# Clarification required on a proof of Schröder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently studying (on my own) the book Sets, Logic and Categories by Peter J. Cameron. The book presents two different proofs of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem. I am unable to understand a certain part of the first proof given in the book. Below, I will present this proof as given in the book and then ask my question:

> We say that $y \in Y$ is the parent of $x \in X$ if $g(y) = x$; dually, $x \in X$ is the parent of $y \in Y$ if $f(x) = y$. Each element of $X$ or $Y$ has at most one parent. An ancestral chain for $z \in X \cup Y$ is a tuple $(z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ such that $z_0 = z$ and $z_{i+1}$ is the parent of $z_i$ for $i = 0, \ldots,n-1$. (Its elements belong alternatively to $X$ and $Y$.) The length of such a chain in $n$ (the number of steps, not the number of elements).
>
> Now there are two possibilities for any element $z$. Either there are arbitrarily long ancestral chains for $z$, in which case we shall say that $z$ has infinite depth; or there is a unique longest ancestral chain for $z$, ending with an element with no parent, in which case we say that the length of this chain is the depth of $z$. (The second possibility includes the case when $z$ itslef has no parent, in which case its depth is $0$.) We let $X_e$ denote the denote the set of elements of $X$ whose depth is even; $X_o$ the set of elements of $X$ with odd depth; and $X_{\infty}$ the set of elements with infinite depth. We define $Y_e, Y_o,$ and $Y_\infty$ similarly.
>
> If $x \in X$ has finite depth, then $f(x)$ has depth one greater than the depth of $x$; and if $x \in X$ has infinite depth, the so does $f(x)$. So $f$ maps $X_e \to Y_o$, $X_o \to Y_e$, and $X_\infty \to Y_\infty$. A similar assertion holds for the action of $g$ on elements in $Y$. Furthermore, elements of $Y_o$ or $Y_\infty$ have parents; so $f$ maps $X_e \to Y_o$ and $X_\infty \to Y_\infty$ bijectively. (This does not hold for $X_o \to Y_e$ since an element of $Y_e$ may have no parent.)
>
> Define a map $h: X \to Y$ by
>
> \begin{equation}
> h(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> f(x) & \text{ if } x \in X_e \cup X_\infty,\\
> g^{-1}(x) & \text{ if } x \in X_o.
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>
> Then it is easily seen that $h$ is a bijection.

I have the following two doubts:

1) In the third paragraph, how did he conclude that the elements of both $Y_o$ and $Y_\infty$ have parents? (I have been able to understand everything else in this proof). Prior to this proof, the only theorem that has been proven is that if there is an injective function from $X$ to $Y$, and $X \neq \emptyset$, then there is a surjective function from $Y$ to $X$.

2) My second doubt is whether this proof is applicable to only countably infinite sets? In other words, if this proof is also applicable to uncountably infinite sets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Simple: 0 is not an odd number.:2) Why wouldn.t it apply to uncountable sets?

Comment: Hi @almagest, Could you please elaborate your answer to my first question? Coming to the second, it was just a distant doubt of mine. I agree, there is nothing in this proof that makes it applicable only to countable sets. Also, please tell me if Axiom of Choice is implicitly used anywhere in this proof? Thanks.

Comment: The definition of $Y_o$ is the elements of $Y$ which have an odd number of ancestors. That means, in particular, that they each have at least one ancestor.

Comment: That clarified my doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y \in Y_o$ means that $y$ has *odd* depth, in particular $y$ does not have depth $0$ as $0$ is even, not odd. And depth $0$ is equivalent to being a non-image. So not depth $0$ means it's an image, i.e. has a parent. So that also trivially explains that $y \in Y_\infty$ (infinite depth) also must have a parent.

Nowhere in this proof the cardinality (countability or not) of $X$ or $Y$ plays a role. We can always define the sets $X_o, Y_o$ etc. based on individual behaviour of points, which determines in which set it lies. And after that the bijection is well-defined, isn't it?